# How to set PHP version for SSH session?

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface

I have setup my account to use PHP v7.0 through Plesk. I then used phpinfo() to verify that I am using 7.0. However, when I login via SSH (command line/shell) and type "php -v", it shows I'm using PHP v5.4. I need to run some PHP through command line, but I need these commands to use 7.0, not 5.4. How do I update the shell to use 7.0?

For example

php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name

I get - cakephp/cakephp 3.6.9 requires php >=5.6.0 -> your PHP version (5.4.16) does not satisfy that requirement.

Any further assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You probably have multiple versions installed. What do you get from `which -a php`?

Comment: yes there are several versions installed on the server. from which -a php I get /usr/bin/php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Plesk all you need to do is following this guide:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003766853-How-to-specify-PHP-version-on-the-Plesk-server-for-command-line-command-php-for-user-

Let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 1):

You can write the complete path to the PHP executable and use the version directly.

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php my_script.php
```

you can replace the `7.0` with any php version you've installed on your system.